# Directive in template of another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying add a custom directive in template of another customer directive but the template is not displayed. Using below code. What Am I doing wrong?

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    
app.directive('container', function () {    
  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        replace: true,
        template: '<div my-dir-one></div>',

        link: function (scope, elm) {           
        }
    }
});

app.directive('myDirOne', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    replace: true,
    template: '<div>This is directive one.</div>'
  }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div container></div>
```

[JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/hdunq2pp/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `replace: true` in the container directive, the end result HTML will be:

`<div container my-dir-one></div>`

The problem is that both of these directives require isolated scopes, and you can't have that (you also can't have more than one directive that requires a template). If you open your console in the dev tools you'll see:

> Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [container, myDirOne]
>   asking for new/isolated scope on: 
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$compile/multidir?p0=container&p1=myDirOn…2Fisolated%20scope&p3=%3Cdiv%20my-dir-one%3D%22%22%20container%3D%22%22%3E

If you remove the `replace: true` of the container directive it will work:

```
app.directive('container', function () {

  return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        template: '<div my-dir-one></div>',

        link: function (scope, elm) {

        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdunq2pp/1/)

Comment: this is my actual problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214894/nested-directive-within-ngview-does-not-work-angular-js